# Chrome extention - using current tab's window function from background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using content script and background script.
On tab loading a function is added to the `window` object.
I will use this example:
 `window.myFunc = function() {...};`

I need to use myFunction from the background script, but because background is running on diffrent `window` -  `myFunc` is not accessible

How can I use `myFunc` from the background script?

Comment: If it's in a different scope it won't be accessible, unless chrome gives you a way to access it.

Comment: I know that. This is why i am asking maybe it is possible with chrome

Comment: Have you checked the Chrome Extension API docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use that exact function which is contained in your content script from your background script.

Your options are:

1. Have the background script [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) to the content script which the content script interprets as a directive to run the appropriate function. The results can be returned to the background script [in a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) (which can be a direct response to the message directing the content script to run the function).
2. Include an identical function with the background script. A single copy of the function's code could be contained in a separate file which is loaded as both a content script and as a background script.  That would allow only one copy of the code to exist, but the actual functions called would be separate instances of the function each generated from the same code.